# htaccess redirect after RewriteRule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have my `.htaccess` written like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule  ^([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/$ /?p=$1
```

and the address like https://mysitedotcom/162/title-of-my-post-id162/ are solved to https://www.mysitedotcom/?p=162

now I have a list of public URLs to redirect to other address, for example:

https://mysitedotcom/200/title-of-post-with-id-200/ redirect to > https://mysitedoccom/100/title-of-my-post-with-id-100/

https://mysitedotcom/201/title-of-post-with-id-201/ redirect to > https://mysitedotcom/158/title-of-my-post-with-id-158/

and so on..

I try with:

```
Redirect /201/title-of-post-with-id-201/ /158/title-of-my-post-with-id-158/
```

but don't work well, beacause in the browser address bar, I see: https://mysitedotcom/158/title-of-my-post-with-id-158/?p=201  and I don't want't to see ?p=201

Comment: no solution ? :/

Comment: ok, this is the solution:

RewriteRule  ^/200/title-of-post-with-id-200/    /100/title-of-my-post-with-id-100/            [R=301,L] 
RewriteRule  ^([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/$ /?p=$1   [L]